# ASP.net displaying data from SQL data source

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL to grab information from my SQL database. I have a GridView which shows all the top level information - in this case a list of groups (i.e. admin, users and so on). When a user clicks say the admin group, I want to be able to show each member in that group. I have the following code which grabs the information from the database:

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

var query1 = from p in dc.Users
             where p.groups.GroupID == Int32.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text)
             select new
                    {
                        p.Name,
                        p.Address,
                        p.Contact Number,
                        p.Bio,
                    };
```

I know that I can use GridView again to display the results of the query, but this doesn't really look nice as it shows too much information at once. How would I go about having some sort of display which will show just one user at a time, giving me the chance to click next and back?

Comment: Use a DetailsView below your gridview. example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what DetailsView is for.  However, I would recommend coming up with your own system.  Trying to shove the functionality you want into the built-in ASP.NET controls is usually an exercise in frustration.

For this sort of thing what I generally do is have the ID column as an asp:Hyperlink that takes the user to the Details page of whatever data you are showing.